# Appengine Cloud Endpoints: NPE on get methods of model objects

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I'm using Cloud Endpoints to retrieve data from appengine to android.  Using the generated library I retrieve a list of objects.  This appears to work fine, and if I log the object I see the json.  However if I use a getX() on the object I get a NPE.  Java GAE 1.8.7. Doing this in an AsycTask in activity.

```
        Builder builder = new Builder(AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(),
                new GsonFactory(), null);
        MyObjectOperations service = builder.build().myobject();
        MyObjectCollection tmp = null;

        GetMyObjects it = service.getMyObjects();
        tmp = it.execute();
        listOfMyObjects = tmp.getItems();

        MyObject test=listOfMyObjects.get(0);
        test.getMyField();     //NPE here - on every field
```

What could cause this??  The listOfMyObjects is the correct size. I have used this client lib before and it worked.  Now it is an updated version.  Any help would be great!

Answer (score 1):

If your `listOfMyObjects` is not an instance of `ArrayList<>` or some other `Iterable`, the `get(0)` will return null, as the list isn't indexed. So, even if the list has n items, it doesn't have a specific nth item, as they're not ordered.

Create an `ArrayList` like this:

```
listOfMyObjects = new ArrayList<myObject>(tmp.getItems());
```

Then `get(0)` should work.